# vmdk to qcow convert is showing issues

Tags: linux, docker

Has anyone come across the below issue when converting a VMDK file to a qcow format?

```
Write failed to dstDisk [####] server1/server1.vmdk curSector 146792448,numSectorToRead 2046 error write /dev/nbd0: no space left on device

CloneDisk: Failed to copy sectors : write /dev/nbd0: no space left on device

CMD: %!(EXTRA *exec.Cmd=&{/usr/bin/qemu-nbd [qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0] []  <nil> <nil> <nil> [] <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> <nil> false [] [] [] [] <nil> <nil>})
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this two-stage conversion (vmdk->raw->qcow) in bash using `qemu-img` QEMU utility (in Debian qemu-utils package).

The script handles single-VMDK or multiple-VMDK files.

```
echo "Converting multiple VMDK files in $PWD into QCOW..."

rm -f tmpImage.raw
for i in *.vmdk; do
    echo "Converting $i ..."
    qemu-img convert -f vmdk "$i" -O raw "$i.raw"
    cat "$i".raw >> tmpImage.raw
done
echo "Creating finalImage.qcow..."
qemu-img convert -f raw -O qcow tmpImage.raw finalImage.qcow
rm tmpImage.raw
```

The only real question is whether we want to append the unsequenced "$i.vmdk" file to the end of its final raw image before converting, but it seems to work best this way.